# How do I ignore an exception?

Tags: scala

Is there more elegant way to write the following?

```
try {
    ... // Some throwing code
    return first
} 
catch {
    case e:ExceptionType => {} // No code to execute. Ignore error.
}
return second
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
scala.util.control.Exception.ignoring(classOf[ExceptionType]) {
  ... // Some throwing code
}
```

Comment: How to do in case the throwing code has to return a value?

Answer (score 18):

@Daniel has already provided the canonical method to use to do this.  Look through the other methods in `scala.util.control.Exception`--they are quite helpful and generic!

If you need to get a return value out of the try block, use `failing` instead of `ignoring` (but be aware that the result is an `Any`, i.e. not typesafe).

You can also write your own exception-catcher, which will be a little slow for heavy-duty work but otherwise nice to use:

```
class DefaultOn[E <: Exception] {
  def apply[A](default: => A)(f: => A)(implicit m: Manifest[E]) = {
    try { f } catch { case x if (m.erasure.isInstance(x)) => default }
  }
}
object DefaultOn { def apply[E <: Exception] = new DefaultOn[E] }

scala> DefaultOn[NumberFormatException](0) { "Hi".toInt }
res0: Int = 0
```

Or if you like options:

```
class TryOption[E <: Exception] {
  def apply[A](f: => A)(implicit m: Manifest[E]) = {
    try { Some(f) } catch { case x if (m.erasure.isInstance(x)) => None }
  }
}
object TryOption { def apply[E <: Exception] = new TryOption[E] }

scala> TryOption[NumberFormatException] { "Hi".toInt }
res1: Option[Int] = None
```

Or you can be inspired by this plus the library routines and create your own methods to ignore multiple different exceptions and preserve types on the return value.

Comment: BTW it could be written a bit shorter with

`handling(classOf[NumberFormatException]).by(_ => 0) { "Hi".toInt }`

Answer (score 5):

In Scala all exceptions are not checked, so if you don't want, you may just skip handling them (and thus exception will be escalated to a higher level). Silently ignoring an exception the way you want to do is generally a bad practice. However, your code can be shortened to:

```
try {
  ... // Some throwing code
} catch {
  case e:ExceptionType => 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hows about:

```
Try { 
     // some throwing code 
}
```

This will ignore all non fatal exceptions, which is what you want to do most of the time.

Comment: What do you mean by non-fatal exceptions?

Comment: Have a look at the source for Try, it calls NonFatal, which considers VirtualMachineError, ThreadDeath, InterruptedException, LinkageError and ControlThrowable to be fatal

Comment: This is not accurate. As of Scala 2.11, this would give a warning at compile time: "A try without a catch or finally is equivalent to putting its body in a block; no exceptions are handled." Indeed, it is identical to not using the Try at all. You have to add a catch to catch NonFatal exceptions, ie catch{case NonFatal(e)=>}

Comment: you're confusing try with Try - which is the main problem with this method of ignoring exceptions